# How can I use a custom-field type that I defined in atlassian-plugin.xml in another module?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

As per documentation, I am creating a new custom field type in atlassian-plugin.xml using the SDK CLI. Now I want to use that new custom field type and create a custom field in another module when the plugin is enabled. However, that module is throwing null pointer exceptions, because the new type is not yet available. The class implementing the type is not annotated as a component - it only gets scanned by spring. It appears the class is instantiated by Jira some time after the plugin has been enabled. How do I know when it is safe to use the new type?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with "/rest/api/2/field" POST option for creating custom fields.

Please refer the URL : 
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/field-createCustomField